# codeigniter variables not initializing on view page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i am new to codeigniter and i am trying to display some data on webpage i have the controller and the model down but my variables daunt seem to be passed to the view page have a look at my code and if u can tell me what is wrong with it tnx for you help.

**Controller:**

```
class Survaycontroller extends CI_Controller{
    // 'QID, Question, qA, qB, qC'
    function index()
    {
        $arrData = array();
        $arrData["qA"] = $this->input->post("qA");
        $arrData["qB"] = $this->input->post("qB");
        $arrData["qC"] = $this->input->post("qC");
        $arrData["Question"] = $this->input->post("Question");

        $this->load->model('survay');

        $survay_data = $this->survay->dosurvay($arrData);

        $viewData['survay_data'] = $survay_data;

        $this->load->view('survay_view', $viewData);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php form_open('survay'); ?>
    <h1><?php echo $Question;?></h1>
    <?php echo $qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qA">
    <?php echo $qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qB">
    <?php echo $qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qC">
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Model:**

```
       function dosurvay($arrData){

            $this->db->select('QID, Question, qA, qB, qC');
            $this->db->from('tblquestions');
            $this->db->where('Question', $arrData['Question']);
            $this->db->where('qA', $arrData['qA']);
            $this->db->where('qB', $arrData['qB']);
            $this->db->where('qC', $arrData['qC']);
            $this -> db -> limit(1);


       $query = $this -> db -> get();

       if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
       {
         return $query->result();
       }
       else
       {
         return false;
       }
     }






}
```

Comment: what is on your `$this->survay->dosurvay($arrData)` how do you return it?

Comment: i added the model page code have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your model returns all data.
YOu have to use foreach since the data is stored inside an array, then you can retrieve it like this.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <?php form_open('survay'); ?>
     <?foreach($survay_data as $survay):?>
    <h1><?php echo $survay->Question;?></h1>
    <?php echo $survay->qA; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qA">
    <?php echo $survay->qB; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qB">
    <?php echo $survay->qC; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qC">
     <?endofreach;?>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi tomexsans i tryed your advice and i received an A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: survay

Comment: its ok i found the problem it was a typo tnx for your help this is exactly what i want

Comment: @EdvinasLiutvaitis glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I honestly have no idea what you're trying to accomplish but there are obvious issues with it.

First in your controller you're assigning post variables, on the first load you aren't going to have post variables so all those lines are going to fail immediately.

Then you're only passing one data variable survay_data to the view, but then you're trying to use $qA etc in the view and those variables don't exist.

If you're expecting to get those from the survay_data array then you need to load them VIA that array as below:

```
<?php echo $survay_data[0]['qA']; ?><input type="checkbox" name="q" value="qA">
```

Comment: all that i want to to is to display the data from the table in a database on a page in <ul> list. can u give me pointers to what is wrong with my code ?